# Rails Pagination - find page number from instance id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

In the case where I have the id of a paginated item, how can I find its page number?

I'm using rails 3 and kaminari.

Unfortunately passing the page number as a parameter is not an option. The paginated items are images of an image gallery maintained by user generated content evolving over time. This means an image may appear on page one on week one but page 2 a subsequent week.

Another option would have been maintaining a numeric order of images (acts_as_list), again this is not possible in my case as photos may appear in multiple galleries of varying scopes.

edit:

Have added a bounty to this as I see this same question asked years ago in various places with no solution. I'm happy to accept an sql query if no active record solution comes up.

Comment: This could be very inefficient but I *guess* it works https://gist.github.com/885484 (haven't tested it yet), it would be nice to get the result using a query but it seems to be a hard problem, I'd love to see another approach without that loop.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. That would work but I was hoping more for a query as this would be slow on large collections.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
# Your "per_page" count
per_page = 30
# Your Image instance:
@image = Image.find_your_image
# SQL. If you're ordering by id, how many lower IDs are there?
position = Image.where("id <= ?", @image.id").count
# Your page
page = (position.to_f/per_page).ceil
```

Now you can wrap it as a class method

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  def page(order = :id, per_page = 30)
    position = Image.where("#{order} <= ?", self.send(order)).count
    (position.to_f/per_page).ceil
  end
end
```

**Usage**

```
@image.page
@image.page(:created_at)
@image.page(:title, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sure this will be fine but haven't had a chance to test it out yet as busy on other stuff.

Comment: Hi again and sorry for delay getting round to this. Your answer works with one correction; to get the position it's necessary to have a <= condition. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One refinement. if you sort by non uniq column results can be wrong . what is working for me - is https://gist.github.com/pironim/5975256

Comment: for similar solution check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365089/find-page-for-given-record-using-kaminari as well

Answer (score 0):

If you find the page id means it will need the some sql queries. instead of that you can pass the page value as a param. This will increase your performance too.

Comment: Thanks Ramanavel. My problem with this is the paginated instance may not always appear on the same page of its associated records. I'll add clarification with regard to this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with but with multiple orders. I only could get it working with a little bad trick.

```
@model = Model.find(params[:id])
page = 1
  if params[:page]
  page = params[:page]
else
  page = (Model.some_scope.order(some_attribute: :desc, updated_at: :desc).pluck(:id).index(@model.id).to_f / per_page).ceil
end
```

It only works good if you don't have to many records in the result of the pluck, otherwise it will get slow.